# How to search for objects using < or <= operator in realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Currently I have `Transaction` objects which have a `transactionDate`:

```
class Transaction: Object {
@objc dynamic var transactionDate: String = "" // yyyy-MM-dd
}
```

I have lots of these objects and I need to delete only the old ones (that are more than two year old) so I wrote:

```
// Since now is 2017-09 I need to delete all objects before 2015-09
// calculations are out of scope here I think :)
realm.objects(Transaction.self).filter("transactionDate < '2015-09-30'")
```

However I get a exception:

> Invalid operator type', reason: 'Operator '<' not supported for string type.

it I cannot use `<` operator for Strings. How can I search
these old strings? (so I am able to delete them)

Comment: Store date as string is bad practice, hard to calculate, why dont you store `NSDate` or timestamp?

Comment: At first I use to store them as NSDates but I realized I was never using  them as dates. I was converting my nsdates objects to strings for the ui the whole time. The format I receive from the server was just perfect for my needs so I decided to leave them as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `<` for a string. Probably a better way is using `Collection`'s `filter` method. You can pass a condition by a closure, then you can convert string object to `Date` object. Like the following:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let filtered = realm.objects(Transaction.self)
    .filter { formatter.date(from: $0.transactionDate)! < formatter.date(from: "2015-09-30")!  }
```

Cons: It doesn't use Realm's native query, so Realm's lazy loading doesn't work. But it isn't a problem because I assume that this process is not called many times.

Comment: Kishikawa-san Thank for quick response. I see. I need to call this at launch time :( I hope so this will not impact launch time. I will try this!

Comment: Would it be possible to implement `<` operator for strings in realm? In this case literal comparison `"2017-09-01" < "2017-08-31"` is just exactly what I need

Comment: Although it is not impossible... But eventually you need to write same code as I shared. Because to compare "2017-09-01" and "2017-08-31" by date order, you need to convert string to date.